# text area is getting inline styles automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-brackets

i want to give a textarea in my form a custom width but the textarea is getting inline styels automatically which are overrriding my custom css styles?? i reviewed my scripts but i don't know which one is manipulating the dom??? please tell me if you know.

this is my markup's head

```
<head>
<title>Demo Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

and these are the only scripts which are at the bottom in my body

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and by the way this is the first page i created and is the only one so i don't have any orther pages that have a textarea field.my text editor is brackets just so you know..

here's how it's rendered in dev-tools

```
<textarea data-brackets-id="173" name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="MESSAGE" style="margin: 0px;width: 183px;height: 54px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: no one has a idea! :(

Comment: You have an inline style attribute on the textarea `style="margin: 0px;width: 183px;height: 54px;"` did you try removing that?

Answer (score 0):

Although the CSS-code is not included, I'm guessing you declare something there about the `<textarea>` tag. You might want to look for `!important` declared behind css-code.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do it on mobile as well as desktop? Check the width of the form element and make the margin width 183px.